# I need to Generate a Report on case object by using Picklist value

Tags: custom-report-type

Field name is STATUS AND picklist value is CLOSED - SUCCESS
and another field is CLOSED DATE

Scenario is (  STATUS(CLOSED - SUCCESS  RECORDS) / TOTAL RECORDS OF CLOSED DATE )

I want Formula for Success Rate to Generate Report

Please Help me Guys

Comment: did you try using summary report ?